# What is this type of C statement called?

Tags: c

In C the following is valid code:

```
if ((a, a+b, a*b) >= 0) {
    ....
}
```

Does the `(a, a+b, a*b)` part have a special name?

Comment: That's a pretty pointless expression. Every part is evaluated, but no evaluations have any standing effect, except the one used to compare with.

Comment: @chris as always except if `a` and `b` are `volatile` in which case the access has side-effects.

Comment: @ouah, Good to look at all of the possibilities.

Comment: @chris, It's just example code used to ask a question.

Comment: I have a special name for it: misleading

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`x, y` is called a comma expression.

`,` is called the comma operator in C and `(x, y, z)` is the same as `((x, y), z)`.

It must not be confused with the comma that separates function arguments and which is not the comma operator.

Comment: Language suggestion: I think "It must not be confused" is better.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that the comma operator evaluates left-to-right, but the result of it is always the right operator. The result of the evaluation of the left operator is discarded. So (x, y) would evaluate to y, so ((x, y), z) equals (y, z). Then (y, z) would evaluate to z.

Comment: A lot of things are worth mentioning about the comma operator: the sequence point after the evaluation of the left operand, it is the operator with the lowest priority in C, the left operand may be of type `void`, the type of the result is the type of the right operand, a comma expression is not a constant expression even if the two operands are constant expressions, etc. etc.

Comment: ...and, it must not be confused with the comma used in variable declaration lists:  `int x, y, z;` is not the comma operator either. It doesn't really matter to the average programmer though, unless you write obscure code like `int x=i++, y=i++;` which is undefined behavior (modifying a variable twice between two  sequence points), unlike `x=i++, y=i++` which is the comma operator and well-defined behavior.